# groovy read file A and output specific lines to file B

Tags: groovy

Can someone give me an example of using filterLine or some other method/mechanism to read all lines in file A that begin with abc and write those lines to file B. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a one line solution for your problem:

```
new File("b.txt") << new File("a.txt").filterLine { it =~ /^abc/ }
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph, very succinct

Comment: Great answer to this real question.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few basic examples.  If you look at the [GDK docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) you'll see that there are options for charset, appending, etc.

```
File fileA = new File('c:/temp/file_a.txt')
File fileB = new File('c:/temp/file_b.txt')


fileA.filterLine(fileB.newWriter()) {
    it.startsWith('abc')
}

fileB.withWriter { writer ->
    fileA.filterLine { it =~ /^abc/ }.writeTo(writer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these techniques/examples John.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but can you try this ?

```
def file = new File("test.txt")
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
file.filterLine(writer) { line ->
line.startsWith("abc")
}
println writer.toString()
```