# Script to read text file line by line and search for a particular word and copy all the lines related to that word to a remote directory

Tags: groovy

I have a text file that contains a large number of log list.

I am trying to use a groovy script to read the text file line by line and search for a particular word called DBC. That word "DBC" should be copied to a remote file directory?

Comment: Hiya! How far have you got with this? Where did you get stuck? Do you have some code that isn't working for some reason? As it stands, this question is probably too broad

Comment: Hey. 
``` 
def myFile = new File("codelooru.txt")
 
myFile.eachLine {line ->
 println line
}
```

now the next step is to copy the all the DBC in myfile

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117956/groovy-read-file-a-and-output-specific-lines-to-file-b

Comment: But with `it.contains("DBC")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Meaning: it is a bad idea to only drop requirements here. Instead: try to solve the problem yourself, and ask specific questions when you are stuck. Dont ask others to do **all** the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for the same. It is just an extended version of what mentioned here [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117956/groovy-read-file-a-and-output-specific-lines-to-file-b)

```
import java.nio.file.Files;

vOldFilePath = new File("C://TestFiles//ReadFile.txt")
StringWriter vOldFileWriter = new StringWriter();
def vNewFilepath = new File("C://TestFiles//WriteFile.txt")
def vfinalString='';
vOldFilePath.filterLine(vOldFileWriter) 
{ vSearchWord ->
        if(vSearchWord.contains("DBC")==true)
        {

            vfinalString= vfinalString+vSearchWord.toString() + "\r\n"
        }
}
log.info "Write your data into file"
vNewFilepath.write vfinalString
```